# Convert to edit where edit has an image causes images in original post to be replaced

Tags: bug

When I deleted an OP answer using the mod `convert to edit` option on [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41143/power-or-energy-signal-doubt/41198#41198), the edit added the edit but didn't update the links to the picture. So the renderer seems to have decided that both pics are reference [1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41143/power-or-energy-signal-doubt/41198#41198).  That caused the unintended replacement of the image in the original question with the image in the `convert to edit` modification.

[Looks like this has been around for a while.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245260/convert-to-edit-feature-messes-up-link-numbers)

Comment: Yeah, happened to me at one point as well. Basically had to manually do the edit.

Comment: @datageist good to know I'm not the only one! Yes, I hand edited it, but it confused me the first time I just used the mod tools. :-)